# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, select-insert

I am creating a web app in which I am executing a select command on my stored procedure, but I want to insert the same fetched data into another table.

So I tried to do something like the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE profinalinstexpensesonid  
    (@from varchar(5000),                
     @to varchar(5000),                
     @trainer varchar(5000),  
     @sonvinid varchar(5000)              
    )            
AS                
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO invoice(sonvinid, tid, date, brandname, zone, location, area, venuename, venue, instructore, amount)  
        SELECT
            instructoreexpense.sonvinid,  
            sonvininsert.trainer,               
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, sonvininsert.date, 105) AS date,
            sonvininsert.brandname,                
            SUBSTRING(sonvininsert.zone, 1, 1) AS zone,                
            sonvininsert.location,                
            sonvininsert.area,                
            companysonvinunitvenue.venuename,              
            sonvininsert.venue,                
            sonvininsert.instructore,                            
            instructoreexpense.amount  
        FROM
            instructoreexpense                 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            sonvininsert ON sonvininsert.sonvinid = instructoreexpense.sonvinid 
                         AND sonvininsert.status = '0'                  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            finalinstructoreexpense ON finalinstructoreexpense.sonvinid = instructoreexpense.sonvinid                  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            companysonvinunitvenue ON companysonvinunitvenue.id =  sonvininsert.comsonvinid                           
        WHERE
            sonvininsert.date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @from, 105)
                                  AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @to, 105) 
            AND sonvininsert.trainer = (SELECT empname 
                                        FROM trainerdetails 
                                        WHERE trid = @trainer)  
            AND instructoreexpense.sonvinid NOT IN (SELECT CAST(Item AS INTEGER)  
                                                    FROM SplitString(@sonvinid, ','))
        ORDER BY 
            instructoreexpense.sonvinid  
END
```

and when I execute the stored procedure like

```
exec profinalinstexpensesonid '01-01-2013','01-01-2017','andrews'
```

I am getting the following error

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure profinalinstexpensesonid, Line 10
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

On my line 10 I have the following code

```
insert into invoice(sonvinid, tid, date, brandname, zone, location, area, venuename, venue, instructore, amount)
```

I don't know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states the size of a column in `invoice` table is less compared to the size of the data being inserted into it.

For example if column `brandname` has data type `varchar(50)` and you are trying to insert more than `50` characters then it will cause error.

To resolve this compare the size of columns in `invoice` with the size of the columns being inserted.

Comment: thank you sir, and what if i want to add a where clause in insert to avoid duplicate values

Comment: @MumbaiWadala , you can add the necessary conditions in the where clause to avoid duplicates.

Comment: what, i dont get you

Comment: @MumbaiWadala , were you able to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check column size of invoice table as well as columns in select list from which you are populating data.

Let's say you are inserting column "B" having data type as `varchar(70)` from table2 in column "A" having data type `varchar(50)` in table1; this won't work as you are trying to insert 70 characters in 50 `varchar` sized column.

Check source & destination column data type & it's length; and change it and try again.